# Docker container exits immediately after running flask app

Tags: python, docker, flask, neo4j, dockerfile

I have gone through lot of answers but could not resolve this issue. Please let me know what I can do to run docker container.

Here is my Setup:

I have Flask app which is making use of Neo4j docker image for DB.It works fine when Neo4j is docker container and flask app is local. I need to build my Flask App to make it docker image. Finally, I will be deploying this application on AWS.

I made my application as Docker image, but when I try to run it immediately exits.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                                      NAMES
eb7f66ffdaa2        re                  "python app.py"          2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                                                 sad_curie
a9a02c84ef9a        re                  "python app.py"          2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                                                                 re
5b55004697f6        neo4j               "/docker-entrypoin..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp   mystifying_galileo
```

My Dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Shantagouda Bk "shantu24@gmail.com"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

This is the error from logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "password"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 124, in driver
    return driver_class(uri, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 65, in __init__
    pool.release(pool.acquire())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 39, in acquire
    connection = self.acquire_direct(address)  # should always be a resolved address
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 398, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    pool = DirectConnectionPool(lambda a: connect(a, security_plan.ssl_context, **config), self.address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 468, in connect
    s.connect(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Please let me know what I am missing and how to run Flask application image.

Comment: It shows your container exiting with a nonzero exit code, which typically means something went wrong.  What do your logs show?

Comment: @larsks I have edited the question with error logs.

Answer (score 3):

Your app tries to connect the DB on `localhost:7687`.

When your app runs native on your host machine, then localhost = your local machine, that's why it works.

But when your app runs within a Docker container, then localhost = app container, so it can't find a DB inside his own container environment.

You should place your DB and your app inside the same network and use the container name of the DB instead of localhost. I recommend to use docker-compose for this task.

Answer (score 0):

As @Munchkin said, you wrongly assume the database is running on `localhost` inside the container. Here's a bit more details on the solution that doesn't require `docker-compose`. You can use [`--network-alias`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) or `--name`.

When running neo4j use:

```
docker run --network-alias neodb neo4j
```

Or:

```
docker run --name neodb neo4j
```

You should be able to access your database on from the Flask container on `bolt://neodb:7687`.

This assumes you are running both containers on the same network. If not explicitly specified, both should be running on the `bridged` network.

For older versions of Docker you may need to use [`--link`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) instead.

For more see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/